# Extract values from multidimensional array and store in separate array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I need to extract values from a multidimensional array. The startpoint is however an stdClass object. The aim is to use the extracted values to create a graph. The graph is not part of this question.

**Question:**

Is there a shorter and more straightforward way, then below?
Note that the values can be 100 so I do not plan to extract the values, one by one.

```
// Create an stdClass.
$products = (object)[
    'group' => [
        ['level' => "12"],
        ['level' => "30"],
        ['level' => "70"],
    ]
];

// Transform stdClass to array.
$products = json_decode(json_encode($products), true);

var_dump($products);

// Calc amount of subarrays.
$amount_of_subarrays = count($products['group']);
$amount_of_subarrays = $amount_of_subarrays - 1; // Adjust since objects start with [0].


// Extract data from [$products], populate new array [$array].

$array = [];

for ($i=0; $i <= $amount_of_subarrays; $i++) {
    $tmp = $products['group'][$i]['level'];
    array_push($array, $tmp);
}

var_dump($array);
```

**Result (as expected):**

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(2) "12"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "30"
  [2] =>
  string(2) "70"
}
```

Comment: In short, not really.  `foreach ($products->group as $group) { $array[] = $group["level"]; }` is about as simple as it can get.

Comment: `array_column($products['group'], 'level')`.

Comment: @Jonnix. If you move your comment to an answer, I will go ahead and approve the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I know of is to use the [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) function which returns `the values from a single column in the input array`

E.g. `array_column($products['group'], 'level')` should return the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You not need the Transform with json_encode and json_decode from stdClass to array 
if use this:

```
$result = array_column($products->group, 'level');
```